# JSPDF : how encode blob in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, blob, jspdf

I am using jsPDF()
And I want to present a document,
I have the value BASE64
And now I want to do a BLOB and return to normal view
How can I do this with JSPDF?

That's the code,

```js
const print = () => {
  const myFont = "";
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text(20, 20, "Name " );
  doc.addFileToVFS("MyFont.ttf", myFont);
  doc.addFont("MyFont.ttf", "MyFont", "normal");
  doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
};
```

I do not know how to add the desired line

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your current code

Answer (score 0):

```
var blobPDF =  new Blob([ doc.output() ], { type : 'application/pdf'});
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF);  //<--- THE ERROR APPEARS HERE

window.open(blobUrl);  // will open a new tab

//window.open(blobUrl,'_system','location=yes'); will open a new window
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the answer already, still want to share for the others
. `window.open(doc.output("bloburl"))`

you can specify other output you want here
https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html#output

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).